# Unexpected reputation changes, fixed after refreshing page

Tags: bug, reputation, caching

I was on a page and my reputation suddenly incremented by 10, and there was no notification at all. When I refreshed the page it went back to my accurate reputation.

3-4 days ago I had a +20 reputation change and it suddenly showed +40 (in total) with a notification of +20. Again, refreshing the page showed my accurate reputation.

Did this happen because somebody up-voted my answer and quickly down-vote it before I received any notification?  Is this normal or just happening to me?

I am using Chrome 49.0.2623.112 m.

Comment: @davidism the issue i emphasis on is completely different issue as recommended by you plus i also mentioned about old cache state for the first part of my question.FYI i was on desktop version.The other part of my  question has most awkward issues.You can read them, They starts form " i was on a.."

Answer (score 3):

When you press the Back button in your browser, it retrieves the previous page from your cache. This not only speeds up loading, but also ensures that what you see is exactly what you were seeing before. Therefore, the reputation score displayed on that cached page has not been updated. If you refresh, or navigate to a new page, then it will reload it from the server, complete with your updated reputation score.

This happens with everyone. It only matters if someone has voted on one of your contributions while you are navigating around the site. It is not really a problem. If you absolutely must see the current number, just refresh the page. Otherwise, don't worry about it. It's just a magic value that randomly goes up or down. If there's something you need to know, you'll get a notification on the site.

Comment: thanks for quick reply and yeah number goes up and down (good one) though i guess the reputation shouldn't go up and down  magically and the last issue where i received a +20 notification and total went up by +40 seems like something a tiny little error. i know this is a huge site and no doubt one of the greatest though the small flaws just feel kind of awkward

Comment: I have never been able to reproduce the behavior you describe, receiving a +20 notification while getting a +40 increase in my reputation score. I've been at this for some 6 years now, and have never seen that kind of bug. Although if this is a very recent bug, I may not have noticed it. I've completely stopped paying attention to the green number up in the top bar; it currently says +2052. It gets reset periodically when I click on it accidentally while aiming for the browser tab bar. I recommend ignoring it as well.

Comment: If you can document this problem with screenshots, it would be very helpful.

Comment: yeah , i was thinking about to take a screenshot when this happened but i neglect it  , next time i will keep this in mind ,although my first attempt toward the improvement of this site seems unimportant to some unkind people (got my only send -2 , yippie).i appreciate you for being supportive

Comment: Bug reports often get downvoted if the problem described cannot be reproduced. That way, the most serious and most reproducible problems appear at the top of the list. Don't take downvotes personally.

Comment: i i Mr.Cody Gray plus i also believe in "do what you can do and enjoy all flavors of life".